# SQLite3 Columns Are Not Unique

Tags: python, database, csv, sqlite

I'm inserting data from some csv files into my SQLite3 database with a python script I wrote. When I run the script, it inserts the first row into the database, but gives this error when trying to inset the second:

```
sqlite3.IntegrityError: columns column_name1, column_name2 are not unique.
```

It is true the values in column_name1 and column_name2 are same in the first two rows of the csv file. But, this seems a bit strange to me, because reading about this error indicated that it signifies a uniqueness constraint on one or more of the database's columns. I checked the database details using SQLite Expert Personal, and it does not show any uniqueness constraints on the current table. Also, none of the fields that I am entering specify the primary key. It seems that the database automatically assigns those. Any thoughts on what could be causing this error? Thanks.

```
import sqlite3
import csv

if __name__ == '__main__' :

conn = sqlite3.connect('ts_database.sqlite3')
c = conn.cursor()

fileName = "file_name.csv"
f = open(fileName)
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
    command = "INSERT INTO table_name(column_name1, column_name2, column_name3)"
    command += " VALUES (%s, '%s', %s);" % (row[0],row[1],row[2])
    print command
    c.execute(command)
    conn.commit()

f.close()
```

Comment: Why did this post get voted down? I think it displayed adequate research background and had a clear explanation of the problem. I certainly did not just copy and paste my code and ask "What's wrong with this?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If SQLite is reporting an IntegrityError error it's very likely that there really is a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY on those two columns and that you are mistaken when you state there is not.  Ensure that you're really looking at the same instance of the database.

Also, do *not* write your SQL statement using string interpolation.  It's dangerous and also difficult to get correct (as you probably know considering you have single quotes on one of the fields).  Using parameterized statements in SQLite is very, very simple.

Comment: Thank you. I am not familiar with the SQLite GUI I am using. I came to the wrong conclusion about that.

Answer (score 0):

The error may be due to duplicate column names in the INSERT INTO statement. I am guessing it is a typo and you meant column_name3 in the INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: Yes. Actually, I just replaced the real columns names with these for privacy reasons. In actuality, those labels a re unique.

Comment: I changed it back to get rid of any ambiguity.